# Receive Azure function's status code and response body when triggered locally via ngrok

Tags: azure-functions, power-automate, ngrok

I am successfully running an Azure function locally via an HTTP request action in Power Automate which is calling my `ngrok` url. This Azure function is in my dev environment, ie. running in VSCode with Azure Function Core Tools, and I've executed `ngrok http http://localhost:7071`.

All of this works fine, my local Azure function gets triggered from Power Automate. However, the status code and response body I get from my `ngrok`'d Azure function is 200 and some HTML describing ERR_NGROK_6022, instead of the Azure function's actual status code and response body. Checking `ngrok`, I see that the Azure function failed and returned a 500 (this is expected for this test I'm running). **However, I would like for ngrok to return this 500 instead of its own 200.**

For comparison, when the Azure function is run in prod, ie. in Azure, the Power Automate action successfully reports the Azure function's real status code and response body.
EDIT: Also the ngrok'd Azure function does return its correct status code when it succeeds, so the issue seems to be that a 500 (perhaps 5XX) in the function is not reported back fully through ngrok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm realizing this happens if an unhandled exception occurs in my Azure function, so the fix is to try/except my main process inside the function. This allows me to return some status code and message back to ngrok and back to Power Automate.